# Unable to get Admob ads in my app

Tags: android, admob

My xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                           ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id"
                           ads:testDevices="@string/test_device"
                           ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Error in logcat:

```
11-05 09:32:30.593: I/Ads(2052): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":18,"session_id":"1804074505668833558","seq_num":"19","slotname":"a150940f47b619f","u_w":320,"msid":"com.ad.aksharamaala.hd","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1","bas_off":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"3.android.com.ad.aksharamaala.hd","hl":"en","smart_w":"full","gnt":8,"carrier":"40407","u_audio":3,"kw":[],"u_sd":1,"mv":"8015016.com.android.vending","isu":"EB83E0FCC98011A7D8B65831A838375F","cipa":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"smart_h":"auto","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":1,"y":480,"x":0,"width":320},"u_h":480,"bas_on":0,"ptime":998246});</script></head><body></body></html>
11-05 09:32:30.953: W/webcore(2052): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
11-05 09:32:30.953: I/Ads(2052): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=18&session_id=1804074505668833558&seq_num=19&u_w=320&msid=com.ad.aksharamaala.hd&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1&bas_off=0&net=wi&app_name=3.android.com.ad.aksharamaala.hd&hl=en&smart_w=full&gnt=8&carrier=40407&u_audio=3&kw&u_sd=1&mv=8015016.com.android.vending&isu=EB83E0FCC98011A7D8B65831A838375F&cipa=0&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&smart_h=auto&u_h=480&bas_on=0&ptime=998246&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-330&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a150940f47b619f&kw_type=broad&askip=3&gsb=wi&caps=interactiveVideo_th_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=40" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
11-05 09:32:30.953: I/Ads(2052): Request scenario: Online server request.
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052): IOException connecting to ad url.
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052): java.net.ConnectException: googleads.g.doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:254)
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:533)
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1055)
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052):    at com.google.ads.internal.f.b(SourceFile:459)
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052):    at com.google.ads.internal.f.run(SourceFile:430)
11-05 09:32:30.973: W/Ads(2052):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-05 09:32:30.973: D/webviewglue(2052): nativeDestroy view: 0x390bf8
11-05 09:32:30.973: I/Ads(2052): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

Can anyone tell me where am I making mistake?

Comment: Have you checked, the url contains banner or not??

Comment: do you have an ad-blocker installed on your (probably rooted) phone ?

Comment: @zrgiu no, I do not have any ad-blocker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you look closely in the log you posted, on line 6 you will notice that `googleads.g.doubleclick.net` resolves to `127.0.0.1`. This usually means that the `hosts` file on your phone was tampered, with the purpose of blocking ads in all your apps.

If you're running this on an emulator, either your emulator's `hosts` file was tampered, or your computer's OS `hosts` file. You should check those out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I know what could be done to solve this issue?

Comment: are you running on a phone or emulator ?

Comment: this app looks like it could do the job for you: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.treb.hosts&hl=en  find the entry for googleads.g.doubleclick.net and remove it